# sign a SHA-256 hash with DSA in Go

Tags: java, go, sha256, dsa

I want to sign a SHA-256 hash with DSA.

Using Java I can write:

```
 Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withDSA");
 sig.initSign(priKey);
 sig.update(new byte[]{1});
 byte[] sign = sig.sign();
 System.out.println(HexUtil.encodeHexStr(sign));
```

Using the Go language, I couldn't find any way to resolve it

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#SignatureAlgorithm lists DSAWithSHA256 as "unsupported", but if there are other built-in ways to do it, I'm not sure.

Comment: I also saw it, but there is no way to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only instance of *checking* a `DSAWithSHA256` signature in go is in [`github.com/avast/apkverifier`](https://github.com/avast/apkverifier/commit/974fc789ac06d98d5c0876c1146afab226e3bd3e)

```golang
    case x509.DSAWithSHA256:
        hash := sha256.Sum256(signed)
        pub := cert.PublicKey.(*dsa.PublicKey)
        reqLen := pub.Q.BitLen() / 8
        if reqLen > len(hash) {
            return fmt.Errorf("Digest algorithm is too short for given DSA parameters.")
        }
        digest := hash[:reqLen]

        dsaSig := new(dsaSignature)
        if rest, err := asn1.Unmarshal(signature, dsaSig); err != nil {
            return err
        } else if len(rest) != 0 {
            return errors.New("x509: trailing data after DSA signature")
        }
        if dsaSig.R.Sign() <= 0 || dsaSig.S.Sign() <= 0 {
            return errors.New("x509: DSA signature contained zero or negative values")
        }
        if !dsa.Verify(pub, digest, dsaSig.R, dsaSig.S) {
            return errors.New("x509: DSA verification failure")
        }
```

But actually *using* the signature algorithm is indeed unsupported, for reason illustrated in [`github.com/grantae/certinfo`](https://github.com/grantae/certinfo/commit/59d56a35515b3ab2326749924739cfe58facc991)

> ### Issues:
>
> 1. Unfortunately, OpenSSL uses non-deterministic signing for DSA and ECDSA certificate requests, so running make-certs.sh will not reproduce the same CSRs despite having static keys.
>    These files have to be kept in-sync manually.
> 2. The x509 package does not currently set `CertificateRequest.SignatureAlgorithm` for DSA CSRs.
>    Therefore the '`leaf2.csr.text`' contains the line '`Signature Algorithm: 0`'
>    instead of '`Signature Algorithm: DSAWithSHA256`' to allow the test to pass and indicate that the problem is with x509 and not this package.

Hence its [unsupported status](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#SignatureAlgorithm) in Go `crypto/x509` package.

Comment: I konw, this way is only verify, i want to konw how to sign .

Comment: on other way , what's the difference  between sha256 then dsa   and  sha256withrsa

Comment: please see my another question,  i found difference golang dsa with java dsa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009710/difference-between-golang-rsa-and-java-rsa