# Difference between Go DSA and Java DSA

Tags: java, go, dsa

1. Go generates a signature using a DSA private key
2. Java verifies first step result using the DSA public key
3. Java should return true, but returns false

```
package main
import (
    "crypto/dsa"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    // a dsa private key
    pemData := []byte("-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
        "MIIBvAIBAAKBgQD9f1OBHXUSKVLfSpwu7OTn9hG3UjzvRADDHj+AtlEmaUVdQCJR\n" +
        "+1k9jVj6v8X1ujD2y5tVbNeBO4AdNG/yZmC3a5lQpaSfn+gEexAiwk+7qdf+t8Yb\n" +
        "+DtX58aophUPBPuD9tPFHsMCNVQTWhaRMvZ1864rYdcq7/IiAxmd0UgBxwIVAJdg\n" +
        "UI8VIwvMspK5gqLrhAvwWBz1AoGBAPfhoIXWmz3ey7yrXDa4V7l5lK+7+jrqgvlX\n" +
        "TAs9B4JnUVlXjrrUWU/mcQcQgYC0SRZxI+hMKBYTt88JMozIpuE8FnqLVHyNKOCj\n" +
        "rh4rs6Z1kW6jfwv6ITVi8ftiegEkO8yk8b6oUZCJqIPf4VrlnwaSi2ZegHtVJWQB\n" +
        "TDv+z0kqAoGBAIb9o0KPsjAdzjK571e1Mx7ZhEyJGrcxHiN2sW8IztEbqrKKiMxp\n" +
        "NlTwm234uBdtzVHE3uDWZpfHPMIRmwBjCYDFRowWWVRdhdFXZlpCyp1gMWqJ11dh\n" +
        "3FI3+O43DevRSyyuLRVCNQ1J3iVgwY5ndRpZU7n6y8DPH4/4EBT7KvnVAhR4Vwun\n" +
        "Fhu/+4AGaVeMEa814I3dqg==\n" +
        "-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----")
    // parse dsa 
    p, _ := ssh.ParseRawPrivateKey(pemData)
    pp := p.(*dsa.PrivateKey)

    // orign data
    hashed := []byte{1}
    r, s, _ := dsa.Sign(rand.Reader, pp, hashed)

    type dsaSignature struct {
        R, S *big.Int
    }
    var ss dsaSignature
    ss.S = s
    ss.R = r
    signatureBytes, _ := asn1.Marshal(ss)

    // print sign 
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(signatureBytes))
}
```

1. **Java reads the DSA public key and initialize a signer**
2. **Java verify first step sign result**
3. **returns false**

```
@Test
public void ttt() throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        // DSA public key
        String pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                "MIIBuDCCASwGByqGSM44BAEwggEfAoGBAP1/U4EddRIpUt9KnC7s5Of2EbdSPO9E\n" +
                "AMMeP4C2USZpRV1AIlH7WT2NWPq/xfW6MPbLm1Vs14E7gB00b/JmYLdrmVClpJ+f\n" +
                "6AR7ECLCT7up1/63xhv4O1fnxqimFQ8E+4P208UewwI1VBNaFpEy9nXzrith1yrv\n" +
                "8iIDGZ3RSAHHAhUAl2BQjxUjC8yykrmCouuEC/BYHPUCgYEA9+GghdabPd7LvKtc\n" +
                "NrhXuXmUr7v6OuqC+VdMCz0HgmdRWVeOutRZT+ZxBxCBgLRJFnEj6EwoFhO3zwky\n" +
                "jMim4TwWeotUfI0o4KOuHiuzpnWRbqN/C/ohNWLx+2J6ASQ7zKTxvqhRkImog9/h\n" +
                "WuWfBpKLZl6Ae1UlZAFMO/7PSSoDgYUAAoGBAIb9o0KPsjAdzjK571e1Mx7ZhEyJ\n" +
                "GrcxHiN2sW8IztEbqrKKiMxpNlTwm234uBdtzVHE3uDWZpfHPMIRmwBjCYDFRowW\n" +
                "WVRdhdFXZlpCyp1gMWqJ11dh3FI3+O43DevRSyyuLRVCNQ1J3iVgwY5ndRpZU7n6\n" +
                "y8DPH4/4EBT7KvnV\n" +
                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        String publicKeyPEM = pubKey
                .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "")
                .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        byte[] publicEncoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyPEM);
        KeyFactory keyFactory1 = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicEncoded);
        DSAPublicKey pubKeyy = (DSAPublicKey) keyFactory1.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        // init signer
        Signature sig1 = Signature.getInstance("DSA");
        sig1.initVerify(pubKeyy);
        sig1.update(new byte[]{1});
        
        // verify first result
        System.out.println(sig1.verify(HexUtil.decodeHex("first step result")));
}
```

---

1. **i tred to use `NONEwithDSA` within the Java implementation but it didnt do it**
2. **Signature sig1 = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithDSA");**

```
java.security.SignatureException: Data for RawDSA must be exactly 20 bytes long
```

---

1. **i tred to use `SHA1withDSA` within the Java implementation but it didnt do it**
2. **Signature sig1 = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");**
3. returns false

Comment: Your golang signature is of "raw / plain" r|s format but Java expects an "DER" encoding. For Java you need to convert the signature to DER format or generate the golang signature directly in DER encoding [as I'm not the specialist in DSA signatures I can not help you any further, sorry.]

Comment: @MichaelFehr: I don't think so. Although OP didn't post data and I'm not a goer (more of a stopper) asn1.Marshal looks to me like something that would generate DER, and in my testing both SUN and BC providers throw an exception for non-DER signature, they don't return false as posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the (Signature) algorithm name `DSA` is an alias for `SHA1withDSA`, i.e. the original FIPS186-0 algorithm. This is **not the same as the nonstandard 'raw' primitive** apparently implemented by Go. `NONEwithDSA` is indeed the correct Java name for what you want, but the implementation in the 'standard' (SUN) provider is something of a kludge that requires exactly 20 bytes of data, not more or less, because that was the size of the SHA1 hash which was the only standard hash for DSA prior to FIPS186-3.

If you (have or can get and) use the *BouncyCastle* provider, it does not have this restriction, and should work for your code changed to `NONEwithDSA` (and either the code or security config modified so that BC is selected as the provider, of course).

If you don't use Bouncy, I think you'll have to code the algorithm yourself; I don't think there's any way to get the SUN implementation to do what you want.

Although it would be *better* to sign a properly-sized hash as specified in the standard, not raw data, and then you could use the Java providers as specified and designed.

Comment: i use golang sha1 orign data    
 hashed := []byte{1}
 sha1 := sha1.New()
 sha1.Write(hashed)
 hashed = sha1.Sum(nil)      
and java use          Signature sig1 = Signature.getInstance("DSA");    can pass